How can I set a cookie in a tsoa endpoint?
I have an express server and am using tsoa to define my endpoints.
I have a login endpoint on the server which returns an auth token which I store in the browser of a web application:
@Route('auth')
@Tags('Auth')
export class AuthController extends Controller {
  @SuccessResponse('200', 'Returns Token')
  @Post('/login')
  public async login(@Body() body: TokenRequest): Promise<TokenResponse> {
    // ... login impl.

    return token
  }
}

Now I have a second application, which will be hosted on a subdomain as the same domain as the first application, that I want to use the same auth for. I would like to set an auth token (and refresh token) cookie so that the token can be shared across the two applications, but I can't find any docs in tsoa or express on how to do this.
Ideally my login function looks something like this:
@Post('/login')
public async login(@Body() body: TokenRequest, @Response() res: Response): Promise<TokenResponse> {
  // ... login impl.
  res.setHeader(...) // or 
  cookie.set(...)
  return token
}

But I can't access the express response in the tsoa endpoint. I've also tried the setHeader method on the tsoa Controller class but that also doesn't seem to work.
Could someone point me in the right direction here? Am I just barking up the wrong tree?

There were a couple of things that I was missing:

I am using axios to make the post request. I needed to add "withCredentials: true" to the request options
In my express cors middleware I needed to add "credentials: true" to the options to allow cookies to be passed
I did use Controller.setHeader from tsoa to set the cookie in the end

